# datepicker - onSelect event is not firing when initialized through datepicker object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to fire the onSelect event as shown below but, it is not working.

I need to use datepicker object as per my application design.

```js
var datePickerObject = $('#datepicker').datepicker();

datePickerObject.datepicker(
  {
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Working"); }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="datepicker"/> //Updated as per Oscar jar suggestion
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `$('#datepicker').datepicker()` running inside `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` ?

Comment: You want alert onShow or onSelect ?

Comment: I want the alert when onSelect is fired

Comment: I think the datepicker plugin is often separate in jquery- ui now.  Are you sure you have the supporting files you need?

Comment: Yes, I do. If you run the code snippet in question, you will see the datepicker.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh you followed my suggestion about the HTML but did you try what I said about the JS code?

Comment: @OscarJara, I am going to try today and will update the status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if wrong but I think what you are doing wrong is that your `datepicker` component is getting ***initialized two times*** when invoking the `datepicker(...)` method for the first time when creating the `datePickerObject` and then again when adding other configurations *(like your `onSelect` function)* to the `object` that was already initialized *(perhaps that's why it isn't working and your function is ignored since it's added in the second time).*

So, if you avoid doing that and you only initialize the component for one time and use the configurations needed *(see example from below)* then you will get it working:

```js
var cfg = {}, 
    cmp = $('#datepicker');

// Add event handlers
cfg.onSelect = onDateSelect;

// Add other configs
cfg.changeMonth = true;
cfg.changeYear = true;
cfg.dateFormat = 'dd-mm-yy';

// Initialize component
cmp.datepicker(cfg);

function onDateSelect(date, cmp) {
  console.log('Selected date is: %o', date);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

---

On the other hand, I wonder why did you have the following in your code snippet:

```
<div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
```

*(Since the `type` attribute is not part of the `div` element)*

If that's what you need then add an `input` for your `datepicker` component, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

---

***UPDATE:***

I've tested your code and passed your event handler when initializing the component only for the first time and it works:

```
var datePickerObject = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    alert('Working');
  }
});
```